# Azure Blob Storage crashes electron app

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

When I am posting a picture from my electron app to blob storage, sometimes it works, and other times I get this error on my terminal:

[image]

When I was first working on this app, this problem never showed up, until a week ago. It occurred without making any changes to this part of the app. Any idea on what could cause it.

The electron app goes white, and the dev tools are disconnected.

Here is the code:

```js
var azure = require('azure-storage');
var blobSvc = azure.createBlobService('*connection keys inside here*');

function createBlob() {
  blobSvc.createContainerIfNotExists('photos', {publicAccessLevel : 'blob'}, function(error, result, response){
    if(!error){
      console.log(response);
    }
  });
  console.log("creating image for student#: " + stud_id);
  blobSvc.createBlockBlobFromStream('photos', stud_id + '.jpg', toStream(imgData), imgData.size, function(error, result, response){
    if(!error){
      console.log("file upload: \n" + JSON.stringify(result) + " \n" + JSON.stringify(response));
      createPerson();
    }
    else if (error) {
      console.log("error: " + JSON.stringify(error));
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you actually call the `createBlockBlobFromStream` immediately, probably without container having created. This may cause the problem.

So, you would need to put them within the callback of the `createContainerIfNotExists` function:

```
blobSvc.createContainerIfNotExists('photos', {publicAccessLevel : 'blob'}, function(error, result, response) {
  if(!error) {
    console.log(response);

    console.log("creating image for student#: " + stud_id);
    blobSvc.createBlockBlobFromStream('photos', stud_id + '.jpg', toStream(imgData), imgData.size, function(error, result, response) {
      if(!error) {
        console.log("file upload: \n" + JSON.stringify(result) + " \n" + JSON.stringify(response));
        createPerson();

      } else {
        console.log("error: " + JSON.stringify(error));
      }
    });
  }
});
```